# Installing Mac OS Big Sur from bootable drive fails

Tags: macos, mac, macos-bigsur

I'm trying to install Mac OS Big Sur to MacBook Pro 13" 2018 from bootable USB drive. Install progresses to about 50% and then I get the notification "An error occurred loading the update." I've tried pretty much everything suggested: disk is formatted, NVRAM is reset, SCM is reset but to no avail. Disk Utils does not find any errors and neither does `fsck -fy` command when I run it from terminal.

Following line is logged to recovery log repeatedly: `configd[43]: inet_set_autoaddr(en5, 1) failed, Operation not permitted (1).`

Could this be a hint on what's wrong?

Comment: I can only guess it's trying to go online to find something - check whether it has latest versions of everything perhaps - & cannot connect. Can you make sure it can see the internet, especially that it isn't trying to use any kind of wifi through a portal structure. Plug it up to ethernet if you can.

Comment: It can connect to the internet. I'm able to browse websites with Safari that is available in recovery mode. I've tried two different wifi's but the result is the same. Really strange. I wish it could do the install just from bootable drive without having to look something online.

Comment: @Kilipukki, did you find a resolution for this?

Comment: @Karoh Yes. When every attempt to reinstall the os failed I took it to authorized Apple repair. They ran diagnostics on the computer and it turned out that memory modules had failed. They replaced the logic board and then the os installed without issues. Luckily, the logic board replacement was covered by warranty.